# Removing artifacts from transparent textures

Tags: texturing, uv, transparency

Im trying to map a texture with transparent but it appears that it has some artifacts around the texture...

[image]

i dont have anything black in my uv:

[image]

Could some one explain to me what is happening ?

Comment: So the artifacts are the black outlines?

Comment: Please add extra information to your question such as what renderer you are using and what viewport mode the 'artifacts' appear.

Comment: Yes they are the black outlines, The render is blender render

Comment: the artifcats appear in any view

Answer (score 1):

In the textures tab you should check the box that sais Alpha and drag it al the way to the right to make the Alpha of the texture 100%. Then go to the material that uses that texture and set the transparancy to 0 so that the material isn't shown but the texture is.